# dompdf add to attachment Laravel

Tags: laravel, dompdf

I wanted to save the pdf file in the laravel rather than download it so it can be attach when creating a mail.

Cant seem to find a save function in the documentation.

```
$document = new Dompdf($options);

//echo $output;

$document->loadHtml($html);

//set page size and orientation

$document->setPaper('a4', 'portrait');

//Render the HTML as PDF
$document->render();

$pdf = $document->output();

//define the receiver of the email
$to = 'toemail@example.com';
$subject = 'SUBJECT -';
$repEmail = 'reply@example.co.za';

$fileName = 'filename.pdf';
$fileatt = $document->Output($fileName, 'E');
$attachment = chunk_split($fileatt);


// Send the email
SendMail::send('mail_templates.default', $data , function ($message) use ($attachment) {
    $eol = PHP_EOL;

    $message->from('us@example.com', 'Laravel');

    $message->to('foo@example.com')->cc('bar@example.com');

    $message->attach($attachment.$eol);
});
```

Comment: There's a closed Github issue which might solve your problem, take a look at [this issue](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/issues/540#issuecomment-456401059)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this as specified in the documention

```
  Pdf::loadHTML($html)->setPaper('a4', 'landscape')->setWarnings(false)->save('myfile.pdf')
```

a sample with your code will look like this

```
//specify the storage location 

 $filePath = storage_path().'/app/Mydocument/'.$now.'.pdf';       
  $document->loadHtml($html);
  $document->save($filePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

$fPath = 'pdfs/' . time() . 'filename.pdf'; // path
Storage::disk('public')->put($fPath, $pdf->output());